# return true or false in a mysql subselect if another field contains a string

Tags: mysql, sql, contains, subquery

I'm trying to return a value of true or false (or yes/no, etc.) as part of a select if a particular field in a table contains a substring.

1. Select the ID, name, and whether or not a person is subscribed.
2. A field called `emailList` has a comma separated list of names which should be used to check if the requester is subscribed. The result of the substring search should yield the true/false value as the result in another field.

---

The basic query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    id,<...>,name
FROM
    table
```

---

In the <...> area, I would want something equivalent to:

```
`emailList` contains @input ? "Yes" : "No"
```

I can't figure out how to do this to save my life. I'm guessing it can be done in other ways, but this seems like a good learning opportunity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT
    id,
    IF(emailList LIKE '%string%', 'Yes', 'No') AS OnEmailList,
    name
FROM
    table
```

Just replace the word "string" with the search term you're looking for or a variable in your server-side programming language of choice.

Comment: Duh! Thanks. I swear I looked for everything except the most obvious programming construct ever created.